# Problem installing fastai on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python

I'm trying to install `fastai`, but nothing seems to work out. I have installed `pytorch` and it is running perfectly.
I tried installing using  `pip3 install fastai`. `pip3` because I have python2.7 along with python3.6.
I upgraded setup tools, that didnt solve the problem.

#### pip3 install fastai

```
Collecting fastai
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/53/da994550c0dd2962351fd694694e553afe0c9516c02251586790f830430b/fastai-2.1.8-py3-none-any.whl (189kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 735kB/s 
Collecting scipy (from fastai)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c8/89/63171228d5ced148f5ced50305c89e8576ffc695a90b58fe5bb602b910c2/scipy-1.5.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 25.9MB 72kB/s 
Collecting torchvision>=0.8 (from fastai)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/43/aaa740c406b1832adc6ff9d5e71c23fd2af2ebd436c42d76d85809ec8be9/torchvision-0.8.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (12.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 12.8MB 142kB/s 
Collecting fastcore>=1.3.8 (from fastai)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/0c/a08940a410b3c55b082578b7142e96afa1c8e3f39972b99366093bb4af59/fastcore-1.3.10-py3-none-any.whl (51kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 1.9MB/s 
Collecting requests (from fastai)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/fc/f91eac5a39a65f75a7adb58eac7fa78871ea9872283fb9c44e6545998134/requests-2.25.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 2.1MB/s 
Collecting fastprogress>=0.2.4 (from fastai)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/1f/c61b92d806fbd06ad75d08440efe7f2bd1006ba0b15d086debed49d93cdc/fastprogress-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pillow (from fastai)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/19/d4c25111d36163698396f93c363114cf1cddbacb24744f6612f25b6aa3d0/Pillow-8.0.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.2MB 580kB/s 
Collecting pandas (from fastai)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/51/bafcff417cd857bc6684336320863b5e5af280530213ef8f534b6042cfe6/pandas-1.1.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (9.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 9.5MB 190kB/s 
Collecting pyyaml (from fastai)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/64/c2/b80047c7ac2478f9501676c988a5411ed5572f35d1beff9cae07d321512c/PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz (269kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 276kB 1.6MB/s 
Collecting scikit-learn (from fastai)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/a1/273def87037a7fb010512bbc5901c31cfddfca8080bc63b42b26e3cc55b3/scikit_learn-0.23.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.8MB 218kB/s 
Collecting spacy (from fastai)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/df/868cb5a40d8649b057594425fe67bffdc732213e6e2fe2ad8ccd2707a918/spacy-2.3.4.tar.gz (5.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.8MB 284kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9n84rlby/thinc/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/wally1002/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 126, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpojkbh6zg', '--quiet', 'thinc<7.5.0,>=7.4.1']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-nf_o3qal/spacy/setup.py", line 252, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-nf_o3qal/spacy/setup.py", line 247, in setup_package
        cmdclass={"build_ext": build_ext_subclass},
      File "/home/wally1002/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/home/wally1002/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/home/wally1002/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 676, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/home/wally1002/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 766, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/home/wally1002/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/home/wally1002/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/home/wally1002/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 732, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "/home/wally1002/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpojkbh6zg', '--quiet', 'thinc<7.5.0,>=7.4.1']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-nf_o3qal/spacy/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally installed it. the problem was pip version. as i'm using both pip and pip3 i was always updating pip. so i updated pip3 using`$ pip3 install --upgrade pip`. it solved the problem.